# How to call a function with database data inside another function?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, function

EDITED: with new code after help from Sgt AJ.

Ok, so I am learning all the time, but since my coder stopped coding for our website, I am now having to learn PHP fully myself.

And I see all the time the coding where my coder made function calls inside other function calls.

So first of all the setup, we have a file for pretty much 95% of all functions in our site. That functions file basically has about 40-50 functions in it.

So I'm asking if someone can explain to me how is this possible to call a function inside another which works in the below instance, but when I try replicate it, it doesn't work? displays no data when I try to echo out the `$user_info`?

Like for example this function below: So Sgt AJ helped me solve the user avatar issue, so that will be removed from this question!

```
function showComments($v)
    {
        $mysqli = db_connect();
        $v = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$v);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cl45-tbn_dir`.`comments` WHERE `v` = ? ORDER BY `id` ASC";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$v);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($myrow['post_approved']==1){
                $user_info = getUserInfo($myrow['poster_id']);

                if ($user_info['user_avatar_type']==1) {
                    $avatar = "https://www.tubenations.com/forum/download/file.php?avatar=".$user_info['user_avatar'];
                } else {
                    $avatar = "https://www.tubenations.com/forum/styles/Flato%20-%20LightBlue%20-%20Main%20Style/theme/images/no_avatar.gif";
                }

                echo '<div class="comment">
                    <div class="avatar">
                        <a href="https://www.tubenations.com/users.php?id='.$myrow['poster_id'].'">
                            <img src="'.$avatar.'" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="name"><a class ="myaccount'.$user_info['group_id'].'" href="https://www.tubenations.com/users.php?id='.$myrow['poster_id'].'">'.$user_info['username'].'</a></div>
                    <div class="date" title="report this post">'.date("d M Y",$myrow['post_time']).'<form action="" class="flag" method="post"><button type="submit" value="'.$myrow['id'].'" name="vote" id="votebutton" alt="vote"><img src="/images/flag.png" alt="report this post!" /></button></form></div>
                    <p>'.stripslashesFull(clean($myrow['post_text'])).'</p>
                </div>';
            }
        }

        $stmt->close();
        $mysqli->close();
    }
```

As you can see, there is a line where it calls another function `getUserInfo`, `$user_info = getUserInfo($myrow['poster_id']);` that is another function inside this file, and that basically connects to our forum database and gets data.

But when I try to replicate this method by using this type of call within another, it doesn't work.

So basically what I was trying to play with was trying to make a function for displaying X users data with this below function

```
    function getYouTubeInfo($page)
            {
                #$id = $_GET['id'];

                print_r ($userdata['user_id']);
                echo $myrow['user_id'];
                echo $userdata['user_id'];

                $db_link = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'HIDDEN', 'HIDDEN', 'HIDDEN');

                  if ( !$db_link )
{
    die('following error occured: '.mysqli_error());
}

$query = "SELECT user_id, yt_channelTitle, channel_id FROM points WHERE channel_id IS NOT NULL AND yt_channelTitle IS NOT NULL ORDER BY channel_id DESC;";
 if($result = mysqli_query($db_link, $query)){
  echo "";

  $i = -1;
  $objectsPerPage = 14;
   $show_records = FALSE;
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {

            if (!isset($_SESSION['last_slide'])) { $_SESSION['last_slide'] = $row['channel_id']; }

                if ($row['channel_id'] == $_SESSION['last_slide']) { $show_records = TRUE; }

                      if ($show_records) 
                        {
                      $i = $i+1;

                        if ($i > $objectsPerPage) { $_SESSION['last_slide'] = $row['channel_id']; echo 'BREAK: ', $row['channel_id']; break; }

                       $page = abs(floor($i/$objectsPerPage));
                       $youtube_info = $row;
                        $userdata = getUserInfo($row['user_id']);

                                if ($userdata['user_avatar_type']==1) {
                                    $avatar = "/forum/download/file.php?avatar=".$userdata['user_avatar'];
                                }   else {
                                    $avatar = "/images/no_image.png";
                                }

                               if (($i/$objectsPerPage)==$page) 
                               { 
                                if ($page !=0) {
                                 echo "</div></div>";
                                }
                                echo '<div class="cslide-slide">
                                <div class="slideTitles">Youtube Users Slide '.$page.'</div>
                                <div class="sections grouped">';
                               }
                    echo '  
                              <div class="cols span_1_of_2">    
                            <div class="memberTitles"><a href="/user/'.$youtube_info['user_id'].'">'.$youtube_info['yt_channelTitle'].'</a>'.$i.';</div>
                                    <div class="memberPicture"><img src="'.$avatar.'" title="Tube Nations Profile Picture" alt="Tube Nations Profile Picture"/></div>
                                    <div class="memberTwitter"><div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="'.$youtube_info['channel_id'].'" data-layout="full" data-count="default" data-onytevent="onYtEvent"></div></div> 
                              </div> ';

                        }
            }

    echo '</div></div>'; 
 }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
echo $_SESSION['last_slide'];
session_destroy();
mysqli_close($db_link);

}
```

So basically in the page in question, `youtube.php`, I just echo this `getYouTubeInfo` function.

This function I need to try get the users profile pictures that are in the forum database which is from the `getUserInfo($id)`.

Also on a side note, I also can not work out how to re arrange the `$i` and `$objectsPerPage` variables and if statements so I can then use the `$page` inside the query `LIMIT $page;` because at the moment the page crashes with no limit, so I have had to put limit to 16 for now.

I use a jQuery slide script for displaying X per slide, so if I can just somehow work out how to make the query further down after the variables and if statements for the page stuff or get any help, I would appreciate it.

EDIT UPDATED REPLY: So now the problem is it now displays X per slide/page, but it now displays a gap after 8 results are displayed when it shows 10, but with a gap, and then on the the next slide button isn't showing up? so Sgt AJ said we need to somehow connect it to the jquery?, so I now will add a tag for jquery. (But can i say a big thanks to Sgt AJ for his help, really appreciate it) :)

Comment: BTW, I meant to say something about this yesterday:  The line `if ( !$db_link )
{
    die('following error occured: '.mysqli_error());
}` is very bad programming practice for a live site.  If an error occurs while someone is viewing the page, the error will expose potentially dangerous information about your code and/or database schema to a user who shouldn't have it.  You should show users a generic error and log the actual error somewhere you can look it up later.

Comment: ok yes, only a few of my functions I made, are done this way, Most of the functions in the functions file are all usually prepared statements.

Comment: Also @Sgt AJ, I noticed something strange that was happening, if you read the new answser post I posted with the details :)

Answer (score 1):

Wow, you've got several things going on here.

First, your query right now says `LIMIT 0;`, which means you should get zero rows returned.  Are you getting data back from this query??

Second, to get the page and items per page working right, you could go with something like this:

1. In your loop, keep your `i=i+1` line
2. Add this if:

`if ($i == $objectsPerPage)`
`{`
`++$page;`
`i = 1;`
`}`

This will increment the page counter once the page is full, then reset the item count for the next page.

Comment: BTW, can anyone tell me why sometimes the page refuses to display a code block, forcing me to reformat like this?

Comment: Ok, but first can i answer as to why i put 0 in `LIMIT 0;` it was to stop the page keep making external calls to youtube while I was trying to work out why I couldn't display and use data from the `getUserInfo($id)` function. I will try what you said with the new if statement, but will that stop the whole data being loaded ? because that is why the page crashes at the moment, because it is trying to ask youtube for over 300 users data lol.

Comment: Where are you changing the $user_info variable?  It looks to me like to will keep requesting the same user's info based on the code I see.  That issue aside, if you set the query to `LIMIT 1` you should only request 1 user's data at a time from the query for testing purposes. (unless this function is being called repeatedly from somewhere else)

Comment: BTW, a loop counter is normally set to 1 or 0 before the loop starts, then incremented at the end of a loop instead of setting it to -1 and incrementing it at the beginning of a loop.  In this case, I would set it to 1 and increment it at the end of your loop.  Otherwise, you will send up with one more item per page than your $itemsPerPage variable.

Comment: yes but that wasn't my problem, I know what the `LIMIT` is for, I know i can set it to 1, but I chose to set it to 0, because I was trying to fetch data from the other function, before I tried to work out how to solve this crash issue.

Comment: ok, well I already had this working in my twitter.php page with the same lines of code. as above ^^ and it displays 8 results per slide page, and i will also have the same problem too on my twitter page, the problem with this slide script is, it loads all hidden data from the other slides all at once, so I need a solution that will load the data it needs for each slide only, so when you click the next/previous slide buttons it loads the data needed for those slides only, and not all when you first goto the page. if you know what I mean?

Comment: Ah, ok.  I'm jsut trying to work through one problem at a time.  :)  In your `showComments()` function, the `getUserInfo()` function is called correctly, because it's using the `$myrow` variable each time, thus getting a different user each time through the loop.  In your `getYoutubeInfo()` function, you're calling it incorrectly, since you keep calling it with the same user info instead of `$myrow`.  It sounds liek both of these are called somewhere else, so you'd need to limit where they're called to prevent 300 function calls in a row.

Comment: ok, so should i make a new function for `getUserInfo($id)` and maybe call it `getUserInfoYoutube($id)` ? would that then work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112735/discussion-between-sgt-aj-and-tube-nations).

Comment: Functions have to appear in other functions to avoid the spaghetti code that plagued mainframes. Consider. Make a cup of coffee. How do I do that? First, boil the kettle. How do I do that? First, fill it with water. How do I do that? Remove the lid, hold it under the faucet ... etc. Fill it with water is called from boil the kettle which is called from Make a cup of coffee. Functions *take care* of things so that the caller doesn't have to worry about them.

Comment: Ok I see Mike, thanks, well Sgt AJ helped a great deal, we was in a chat room on SO, and he helped a lot. but we left it where we ran out of options on how to next proceed, because we added more code to the function, and resolved the get user avatar issue but now we have another issue. I will update my question with the new edited code.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add more to my question, I think now the answer is with AJAX, so I think I need to somehow make the cslide jquery code recall the `getYoutubeInfo($page)` function

the jquery code for the cslide is this:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.cslide = function() {

        this.each(function() {

            var slidesContainerId = "#"+($(this).attr("id"));

            var len = $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide").size();     // get number of slides
            var slidesContainerWidth = len*100+"%";                     // get width of the slide container
            var slideWidth = (100/len)+"%";                             // get width of the slides

            // set slide container width
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slides-container").css({
                width : slidesContainerWidth,
                visibility : "visible"
            });

            // set slide width
            $(".cslide-slide").css({
                width : slideWidth
            });

            // add correct classes to first and last slide
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slides-container .cslide-slide").last().addClass("cslide-last");
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slides-container .cslide-slide").first().addClass("cslide-first cslide-active");

            // initially disable the previous arrow cuz we start on the first slide
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-prev").addClass("cslide-disabled");

            // if first slide is last slide, hide the prev-next navigation
            if (!$(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active.cslide-first").hasClass("cslide-last")) {           
                $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-prev-next").css({
                    display : "block"
                });
            }

            // handle the next clicking functionality
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-next").click(function(){
                var i = $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").index();
                var n = i+1;
                var slideLeft = "-"+n*100+"%";
                if (!$(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-last")) {
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").removeClass("cslide-active").next(".cslide-slide").addClass("cslide-active");
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slides-container").animate({
                        marginLeft : slideLeft
                    },250);
                    if ($(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-last")) {
                        $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-next").addClass("cslide-disabled");
                    }
                }
                if ((!$(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-first")) && $(".cslide-prev").hasClass("cslide-disabled")) {
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-prev").removeClass("cslide-disabled");
                }
            });

            // handle the prev clicking functionality
            $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-prev").click(function(){
                var i = $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").index();
                var n = i-1;
                var slideRight = "-"+n*100+"%";
                if (!$(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-first")) {
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").removeClass("cslide-active").prev(".cslide-slide").addClass("cslide-active");
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slides-container").animate({
                        marginLeft : slideRight
                    },250);
                    if ($(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-first")) {
                        $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-prev").addClass("cslide-disabled");
                    }
                }
                if ((!$(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-slide.cslide-active").hasClass("cslide-last")) && $(".cslide-next").hasClass("cslide-disabled")) {
                    $(slidesContainerId+" .cslide-next").removeClass("cslide-disabled");
                }
            });



        });

        // return this for chainability
        return this;

    }

}(jQuery));
```

I also tweaked the code that Sgt AJ helped me with again, By adding a `session_destroy()` just before the closing brace. And also a few other bits, because I noticed that when you refreshed the page over and over, it just loaded the next 14 results, instead of the same first 14 results, so the actual code and logic seems to be working. so it is basically now down to we need to find a way to use AJAX and recall the function from the onclick event of the next/previous buttons.